# How to convert existing array of string to custom object array in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have some existing data and I want to update it but I can't able to build a query for that.
I want to convert and update Options field which is string array to object array.
Is it possible or not?

I tried arrayToObject but it doesn't work
Below is my existing record:

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b6455d9c006ae9d142b0da8"),
    "PartnerId" : "585938e3d4e9dac9bb2b09c6",
    "BusinessID" : NumberLong(98),
    "Responses" : [ 
        {
            "QID" : 1,
            "Order" : 1,
            "Question" : "Contact Information 1",
            "Options" : [ 
                "First Name", 
                "Address", 
                "Email", 
                "Phone"
            ],
            "Answers" : [ 
                "First Name", 
                "111, Dublin, California, 94568", 
                "forms1@vagaro.com", 
                "111"
            ]
        },        
        {
            "QID" : 8,
            "Order" : 6,
            "Question" : "Contact Information 2",            
            "Options" : [ 
                "Address",
                "Email" 
            ],
            "Answers" : [ 
                "5000 Estate Enighed, Independence, Kansas, 67301"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Expected result:

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b6455d9c006ae9d142b0da8"),
    "PartnerId" : "585938e3d4e9dac9bb2b09c6",
    "BusinessID" : NumberLong(98),
    "Responses" : [ 
        {
            "QID" : 1,
            "Order" : 1,
            "Question" : "Contact Information 1",
            "Options" : [ 
                {Option:"First Name", Order:1}, 
                {Option:"Address", Order:2}, 
                {Option:"Email", Order:3}, 
                {Option:"Phone", Order:4}
            ],
            "Answers" : [ 
                "First Name", 
                "111, Dublin, California, 94568", 
                "forms1@vagaro.com", 
                "111"
            ]
        },        
        {
            "QID" : 8,
            "Order" : 6,
            "Question" : "Contact Information 2",            
            "Options" : [ 
                {Option:"Address", Order:1},
                {Option:"Email" , Order:2}
            ],
            "Answers" : [ 
                "5000 Estate Enighed, Independence, Kansas, 67301"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Please help me.
Thanks

Comment: You can easily update the doc with the script.

Comment: Thanks, Rohan but can you please explain in detail how?

Comment: which framework/language are you using to interact with DB? How many records are there?

Comment: I want to update it

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/) like follows. I used mongo shell with the same document you described.

```
db.test.aggregate([
    { $match: {} },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: "$_id",
            PartnerId: "$PartnerId",
            BusinessID: "$BusinessID",
            Responses: {
                $map: {
                    input: "$Responses",
                    as: 'response',
                    in: {
                         "QID" : "$$response.QID",
                         "Order" : "$$response.Order",
                         "Question" : "$$response.Question",
                         "Options" : {
                             $map: {
                                 input: "$$response.Options",
                                 as: 'option',
                                 in: {
                                     Option: "$$option",
                                     Order: {
                                         $sum: [
                                             {
                                                 $indexOfArray: [
                                                     "$$response.Options",
                                                     "$$option"
                                                 ]
                                             },
                                             1
                                         ]
                                     }
                                 }
                             }
                         },
                         "Answers" : "$$response.Answers"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    { $out: 'output' } 
])
```

Will output the desired documents to the collection `output`. You can check it and rename it later or just specify another collection name in the `$out` stage if you want to override/create another collection.

Comment: Thanks Carlo, but this is not my answer. I want to update existing records in same collection.